# задержка перед PJAX плагином

Tags: jquery, ajax, pjax

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему: использую pjax плагин для перемещения между страницами навигации.

Все работает, но есть проблема - нужно сделать задержку перед переходом на другую страницу, т.к. не видно гифки загрузки, да и нужно определенную анимацию сделать перед таким переходом

Код main.js:

```
$(function() {

// jQuery PJAX
$(document).pjax('.navbar-brand, .description, .placement, .around, .genplan, .ipoteque, .gallery, .documents, .contacts', '#content', { fragment: '#content' });

$.pjax.defaults.timeout = 2500;

// .pjax - класс меню навигации
$('.pjax').bind('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#content').on('pjax:beforeSend', function() {
                // LOADING
                $(".loading").addClass("show");

            });

            $('#content').on('pjax:success', function() {
                // END OF LOADING
                $(".loading").removeClass("show");
            });

            // Пробую запилить анимацию перед переходом pjax
            var anim = $('.center-block img').animate({
                    'margin-left': '1000px'
                }, 1000);
        }
    })
})



// Active links after click
$('.navbar-nav li').bind('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
$('a.navbar-brand').bind('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
})

})
```

я уже пытался всевозможными способами: сначала менял опцию `timeout` у плагина, потом пробовал перед нажатием на ссылку меню сделать ajax-запрос, и осуществить в php с помощью `sleep()` задержку, но в пустую.

Пример: http://www.lisles.ru/

В общем, как новичек, буду очень признателен за помощь!